# JavaScript string concatenation not working

Tags: javascript, html

This javascript code to concatenate isn't working.  I tried an alert before closure of script tag, it's displayed but the code below that I want to display the result in third or different text field.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="field"><br>
<input type="text" id="str2"><br>
<input type="text" id="str3"><br>
<button onclick="concate()">Concatenate</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var s=document.getElementById("field").value;
var t=document.getElementById("str2").value;
var st=document.getElementById("str3").value;

function concate()
{
    st=s+t;
    document.getElementById("str3").value.innerHTML=st;
    console.log(st);
    document.write(st); 
}
```

Comment: For your information: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no function `.value.innerHTML` should be :

```
document.getElementById("str3").value = st;
```

Also you should get the fields value inside function and close your function definition using `}`, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function concate()
{
     var s=document.getElementById("field").value;
     var t=document.getElementById("str2").value;

     document.getElementById("str3").value=s+t;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field"><br>
<input type="text" id="str2"><br>
<input type="text" id="str3"><br>
<button onclick="concate()">Concatenate</button>
```

Comment: To confirm and clarify: when you get the values (in the question code), is when the script first runs (probably on load and most likely blank), not when you run `concat`.  So any changes to the inputs occurs after you have already populated `s` and `t`.  By putting them inside the function, you read the current values when the function is called.

Comment: Thenks @freedomn-m for your intervention don't hesitate to edit the post directely by adding your explication.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function concate() {
    var s=document.getElementById("field").value;

    var t=document.getElementById("str2").value;

    var st=document.getElementById("str3").value;
    // this is a standard way to concatenate string in javascript
    var result = s+t;
    document.getElementById("str3").value=result;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field"><br>
<input type="text" id="str2"><br>
<input type="text" id="str3" readonly><br>
<button onclick="concate()">Concatenate</button>
```

Comment: Why do you use concat instead of `+`?

Comment: *"This is a standard way to concatenate string in javascript"* - no, it's not.

Comment: .concat() is used for Arrays, for strings you use the +

Comment: maybe i should delete the answer then??

Comment: @Transformer you can read refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method

Comment: without answering today i wouldnt have sen the difference