# Most efficient way to concat strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

What will be the fastest and most appropriate way to concat or merge two strings.
By using the '+' operator :

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1 + str2;
// output : "Hello world!"
```

Or using the string concat :

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
// output : "Hello world!"
```

The perspective is if the code has to be fast and optimized and production quality.And the above method will be used for constructing links,href and custom statements.. etc.
Is there any other method to do so effeciently.

Comment: This depends on the engine, but should be nearly equal. But if the string concatenation is a bottleneck in you code then you have another problem then using `+` or `concat`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method here you find the answer i think

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/

Comment: [Always read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Performance).  Also, [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't know if it's the fastest way, but what I find most readable (i.e. optimized for human eyes) is:

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = [str1, str2].join('');
// output : "Hello world!"
```

Although usually only when we don't know ahead of time exactly what is going to be concatenated, so the sample looks really contrived.

Comment: Is it? Personally `+` is better for me.

Comment: @Albzi it forces me to keep all the strings to be concatenated in one place (inside the array definition, so not littered throughout who knows where) and theoretically allows the runtime to know exactly how much memory is needed to store the end result so potentially less memory allocation. ymmv ofcourse.

Comment: @damitj07: it feels a bit weird that you would have selected this as your preferred answer, isn't Champagne's answer a better fit for you/your question?

Comment: Yes it would have been,but your answer sir , provides a new way and bit more customization ...as I may decide to concat with a special character in between. So that is what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already [answered in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method) using the `+` operator is more effective.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) page about `concat`

> It is strongly recommended that assignment operators (+, +=) are used
>   instead of the concat() method.