# How to concatenation two strings in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to concatenate these two string `emp_name` and `emp_post`. Suppose `emp_name` is `joshi` and `emp_post` is `ldc`.
I want to get `joshi ldc`

```
$('#emp_name').val(res.emp_name);
$('#emp_post').val(res.emp_post );
```

But I don't know how to concatenate these two string. My full Code is below:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {});
    function my_validate_func() {
    var emp_id = $('#emp_id').val();
        if ($('#emp_id').val() != "" ) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'check_ccl.php',
            data: { emp_id: emp_id},
            success: function(response) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(response);
                $('#emp_name').val(res.emp_name);
                $('#emp_post').val(res.emp_post );
            }

        });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS strings "+" vs concat method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to concatenate strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696632/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in javascript you can use  + for concatenate string

so

```
success: function(response) {
        var res = $.parseJSON(response);
            $('#emp_name').val(res.emp_name);
            $('#emp_post').val(res.emp_post );
          var my_res  =  res.emp_name + ' ' + res.emp_post;
          // you can se the result in console for test
          console.log(my_res); 
        }
```