# How to concat url in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

I have common-class has commonUrl, this commonUrl i used in category.service.ts but it not concat in service.ts how to concat this commonUrl in angular 6?

common-class.ts

```
export class CommonClass {
  constructor(public commonUrl : string = 'http://localhost:3000'){};
}
```

category.service.ts

```
import { CommonClass } from '../classes/common-class';
commonUrlObj : CommonClass = new CommonClass();

saveNewCategory(formData){
  return this.http.post('this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl'+''+'/saveNewCategory',formData).map((res: any) => res.json());
}

getCategoryDetails(param){
  return this.http.post('this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl'+''+'getCategoryDetails',param).map((res: any) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: i think it should be ```return this.http.post(this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl +'/saveNewCategory' + formData).map((res: any) => res.json());```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS strings "+" vs concat method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd advice you to use a string literal. Using `` ` ``, resulting in `` `${this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl}/saveNewCategory` ``

Comment: using the above template literal is the recommended way. If you use `+`, it will result in a code smell defect if you are running a tool like Sonar.

Answer (score 1):

remove `single quotes` from `'this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl'`

```
saveNewCategory(formData){
  return this.http.post(this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl+'/saveNewCategory',formData).map((res: any) => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the single quotes and it should work.

```
return this.http.post(this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl+'/saveNewCategory',formData).map((res: any) => res.json());
```