# import as variable and concatenation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I found this piece of code in github and I don't understand it

```
function writeClients(dictionary: IReferenceDirectory[]) {
//more code here

  let superClientFile = `import IClientOptions from './base/IClientOptions';\n`;
  superClientFile += `import Transport from './base/Transport';\n\n`;
```

source: https://github.com/Silind/twitter-api-client/blob/c8d724f38a9ed7112cd112ce11f2013f21b4740f/src/generator/writeClients.ts#L11

why don't the author import at the most top? What's the intention here? and he use `+=` too

Comment: it seems like the code is generating a new js or ts file to be executed, whatever written in that file is going to be executed seperately.

Comment: `+=` concatenates ... what would you use?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the library dynamically builds the `TwitterClient` class with fields and methods depending on the passed `dictionary` argument. At the end of the referenced file, you can see that the generated class is written to disk:

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${generatedPath}/index.ts`, superClientFile);
```

So it seems that this is a fancy way of generating the `TwitterClient` that can later be imported in your app. Also building the class content using `+=` concatenation is considered the way to go nowadays, see [JS strings "+" vs concat method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It imports the selected files based on clients.

```
clients.forEach((client) => {
  superClientFile += `import ${client} from './clients/${client}';\n`;
});
```

And at the end of the file, it writes the code into the file `index.ts` so above two import lines should be included in `superClientFile` string.
That is the code of file - `index.ts`

```
...
superClientFile += '}\n\nexport default TwitterClient;\n';
fs.writeFileSync(`${generatedPath}/index.ts`, superClientFile);
```