# what does the '+' sign do in "url(" + imageUrl + ")"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Was reading some jquery code form [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-set-css-background-image-property-using-jquery.php). What does the + sign and spaces do in "url(" + imageUrl + ")"   ?

I m new to jquery and js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQuery Setting background-image CSS Property</title>
<style>
    .box{
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 5px solid #333;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set background image of a div on click of the button
    $("button").click(function(){
        var imageUrl = "images/sky.jpg";
        $(".box").css("background-image", "url(" + imageUrl + ")");
    });    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p><button type="button">Set Background Image</button></p>
</body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: It [concatenates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method) the string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#concatenating_strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can concatenate strings by using the `+` sign.

For example,

```
let string1 = Hello;
let string2 = World;
let fullString = string1 + string2; // This is now: HelloWorld.
```

So basically your code is just appending the `imageUrl` to the `url()`.

In the end you will have something like `url("images/sky.jpg")`;

Answer (score 1):

The plus (`+`) operator has several usages in JavaScript. The actual action that the plus operator does is defined by the context in which the operator is located.

In a numerical context this operator is used for addition

`1 + 2 // 3`

In a string context it's used for concatenation
`'1' + '2' // '12'`
`1 + '2' // '12'`